# Create method to work as operator

Tags: c++

Is it possible in C++ to create custom method which will work as overloaded operator? For example simple class:

```
class A
{
public:
  A(int val){ x = val;}
  int getInt(){ return (x + 2); }

private:
  int x;
};
```

How to do method `toSpecialString` which will, for example, format my returned `int` in a special way and then return this `string` (e.g "abc14"). Example:

```
A a(12);
std::cout << a.getInt().toSpecialString() << std::endl;
```

As output I'm expecting "abc14". Is something like that possible in C++?

Comment: The problem is `a.getInt()` returns an `int` not an object.

Comment: Why not just give `A` the method `toSpecialString`? You could also return an intermediate type from `getInt` that does have a method `toSpecialString`.

Comment: If you want to have this syntax you'll have to go the Java route and wrote a `Int` class that behaves like an `int` but allows you to add member functions to it.

Comment: There's a _type cast_ operator you can overload, not sure if that's what you mean to do.

Comment: Or write a free function `toSpecialString(int)` used like `toSpecialString(a.getInt())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, for example

```
class A
{

  struct ReturnedInt {
    int x;

    // constructor
    ReturnedInt(int x_) : x(x_) { }

    // "transparent" type cast to int
    operator int() { return x; }

    std::string toSpecialString() {
      std::ostringstream oss{};
      oss << "abc" << x;
      return oss.str();
    }
  };

public:
  A(int val){ x = val;}
  ReturnedInt getInt(){ return (x + 2); } // I changed the return type but see the remarks below

private:
  int x;
};
```

Then

```
int main () {
  A a{12};
  std::cout << a.getInt() << '\n';
  std::cout << a.getInt().toSpecialString() << '\n';
}
```

prints

```
14
abc14
```

where the former was passed to the `cout`'s `operator<<` as a plain `int` (decaying automatically) but in the latter we use the fact that the return value is actually an object. For the same reason as the former line, any function expecting an `int` will also accept `ReturnedInt`. Moreover, in the compiled binary this kind of "wrapper" structure should come at zero additional cost.

Note that the inner class can be private (like in my example) if you don't intend to expose it for any other purposes. This does not collide with the fact that it's used as a return type or that its (public) methods are invoked.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

`a.getInt().toSpecialString()` does not work since `a.getInt()` returns an `int`. An `int` is not a class and hence, cannot have a member function.

Possible solutions:

1. Add `toSpecialString()` as a member function.

   ```
   class A
   {
      ...

         std::string toSpecialString()
         {
            return std::string("abc") + std::to_string(getInt());
         }
   };
   ```

   and use it as:

   ```
   a.toSpecialString();
   ```
2. Add another class to create a string.

   ```
   struct MyStringFormatter
   {
      std::string toSpecialString(int x)
      {
         return std::string("abc") + std::to_string(x);
      }
   };
   ```

   and use it as:

   ```
   MyStringFormatter().toSpecialString(a.getInt());
   ```

   If necessary, `MyStringFormatter` can be updated to take an instance of `A` and return the string.

   ```
   struct MyStringFormatter
   {
      std::string toSpecialString(A a)
      {
         return toSpecialString(a.getInt());
      }

      std::string toSpecialString(int x)
      {
         return std::string("abc") + std::to_string(x);
      }
   };
   ```

   and can be used as:

   ```
   MyStringFormatter().toSpecialString(a);
   ```

My recommendation would be to use the second method. It separates class `A` from the special logic used to format an `int`.